# How to input the currently in use column in conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets

Thanks to all members of this wonderful community.

Here i am trying to conditional format column W ( Range- W4:1000) to show colour if the corresponding values in Column E is greater. =E4>W4 seems to do the job for me. i am new into excel & sheets, so i am trying and some things work, some don't. First Q. is this the right formula i am using ?
Since this works well.

Now Q.2 and important one , that if i enter a new column in between say right of E, the conditional formatting gets messed up as now W column becomes X. How to avoid that ?

[image: ex]

Comment: Doesn't it automatically change it to =E4>X4?

Comment: @TomSharpe got it.. my wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For the first question:

I think the correct formula you want to use should be `=E4:E1000>W4:W1000` assuming that you will only have values up to row 1000.

#### For the second question:

The formula used in conditional formatting should automatically adjust when the columns/rows used have changed.

Please let me know if I answered all your questions.